# Problemas com código em python no file i/o

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

Olá, sou iniciante em python, estou programando no 3.5.1, estava fazendo um trecho de código que lê e depois retira uma linha de um arquivo:

```
lista = {}  
# Essa função lê o arquivo e divide ele em linhas, em palavras e depois coloca dentro de um dicionario
# e a primeira palavra de uma linha é a chave das outras palavras da linha
def upd():  
    file = open("bd.glc","rt")  
    text = list(map(lambda l: l.split(" "),file.readlines()))  
    file.close()  
    p = 0  
    while p < len(text):  
        text[p][-1] = text[p][-1].replace("\n","")  
        p += 1  
    p = 0  
    while p < len(text):  
        lista.update({text[p][0]:text[p][1:-1]})  
        p += 1  
upd()  
# Pergunta qual cliente deve ser deletado
resd = input("\nQual o id do cliente\n>>>")  
if resd in lista:  
    file = open("bd.glc","wt")
    # Aqui é dificil de explicar mas basicamente escreve no arquivo todas as linhas menos a linhas
    # com a chave que vai ser deletada  
    for k,v in lista.items():  
        if k == resd:  
            continue  
        else:  
            file.write(k)  
            for i in v:  
                file.write(" " + i)  
            file.write("\n")
```

http://pastebin.com/BHdnKSQj

E ele está apagando o arquivo inteiro em vez de apagar o arquivo e colocar todas as linhas menos a que deve ser apagada.(o programa deveria fazer isso porque não sei como apagar um texto diretamente no arquivo)

Comment: Poste por favor o código para vermos o que pode estar errado

Comment: Cadê o código? Posta aí cara.

Comment: A foi sem quere, não sei porque o editor não postou o link, vo tenta coloca

Comment: Não tenho tempo de rsponde ra gora - mas duas dicas rápidas: (1) de fato é impossível "apagar uma inha diretamente dentro de um arquivo de texto"  - é só pensar, e vai ver que não tem como isso acontecer diretamente sem ter um código como o que você quer. (2) Em Python, o "for" sempre precorre uma sequencia - se você usar com uma lista, não há a manor necesidade desses `while i < len(p): `  - apena s `for line in  p ` ; (3) mesmo assim, não há necessidade dessas pós-transofrmações na lista: transforme já quando ler o arquivo na primeira vez.  Veja a dcumentação do método "split".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz uma versão um pouco mais simplificada com algumas boas práticas do python.

```
file_name = 'test.txt'


def read_file():
    with open(file_name, 'r') as reader:
        content = [line.split() for line in reader.readlines()]
    # se a primeira palavra da linha se repetir será sobrescrita
    return {line[0]: ' '.join(line) for line in content}


def write_file(file_content):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as writer:
        for line in file_content.values():
            writer.write('{}\n'.format(line))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_content = read_file()
    key_to_remove = input('Qual o id do cliente\n>> ')
    if key_to_remove in file_content:
        file_content.pop(key_to_remove)
        write_file(file_content)
```

Basicamente esse script tem:

- Uma função para ler o arquivo e retornar seu conteúdo em um dicionário (sendo a chave a primeira palavra da linha que foi lida, como você estava pretendendo fazer)
- Uma função para escrever no arquivo de texto o conteúdo do dicionário (somente os valores)
- No final onde é verificado se esse script [é o que está sendo executado pelo python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html), leio o arquivo, solicito ao usuário o "id" da linha que ele quer remover e caso esse "id" esteja no dicionário (que contem o conteúdo do arquivo), removo esse registro do dicionário e reescrevo o arquivo.

Alguns "idiomas" que podem ser novidades para você:

- [with](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) : Usamos o `with` aqui para envolver o uso do arquivo que foi aberto através da função `open` em um [contexto](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager). Com isso, você não precisa se preocupar em fechar o arquivo e correr o risco de deixa-lo aberto (o que pode ter sido o seu problema), o context manger cuida disso, ao sair do contexto o arquivo será fechado
- [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) e dict comprehensions: basicamente eu simplifiquei uns dois `for` usando list comp (`[x for x in some_iterable]`) e dict comp (`{key: value for key, value in some_iterable}}`)

Tente implementar dessa forma e se surgirem duvidas pode comentar e perguntar.

Comment: Obrigado, mas uma coisa que ainda não entendi ai foi o format

Comment: O format é um método da classe string que é usado para formatar strings, de uma olhada nesse link, tem um tutorial excelente https://mkaz.tech/python-string-format.html